OpenLayers style function failed to parse "[object Object]" as color
I want to apply different colors to point features (trees) depending of the property 'art' and add a label (num).
My code works so far, but regularly the map 'disappears' (stay empty) when activating the layer (trees) in the layer-switcher until I pan or zoom.
In the browswer I get following error, :
Uncaught Error: failed to parse "[object Object]" as color
Here is the code I use:
    // define colors for different species of trees
    var artColors = {
        Ap: 'rgba(173,255,47,0.8)',
        Bi: 'rgba(255,255,0,0.8)',
        Ki: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.8)',
        Pf: 'rgba(128,0,128,0.8)'
    };

    // Style trees 
    var functionArtStyle = function(feature) {
        var art = feature.get('art');
        var artColor = artColors[art] || {};
        var label = feature.get('num');
        var artstyle = new Style({
                    image: new Circle({
                        radius: 5,
                        fill: new Fill({
                            color: artColor}),
                        stroke: new Stroke({
                            color: artColor, 
                            width: 2.5})
                    }),
                    text: new Text({
                        text: label,
                        font: "11px Verdana,sans-serif",
                        fill: new Fill({
                            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0)'
                        }),
                        stroke: new Stroke({
                            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)',
                            width: 2.5
                        }),
                        offsetY: -15,
                    })
                });
        return artstyle;
    };

    var trees = new VectorLayer({
        title: 'Trees',
        visible: false,
        minZoom: 12,
        source: new VectorSource({
            format: new GeoJSON(),
            url: function (extent) {
                return (
                    expressBaseUrl + '/trees' +
                    '?bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',4326'
                );
            },
            strategy: bboxStrategy,
        }),
        style: functionArtStyle,
        declutter: true

    });


var artColor = artColors[art] || {};  'color' should be set to a valid color string.  An empty object {} is not valid.

great Mike I changed my code to let artColor = artColors[art] || {default:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)'}; so that there is a default color (white,0.8) set, when no matching is found.
